# Rails 5 - Sum of children after applying WHERE to parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails 5 app I have passengers, flights and extras.

A passenger has many flights and a flight has many extras.

Both, the flight and the extra model have a field Value.

I am trying to get all Extras from all flights (within a date range) and get the sum of their values.

```
passenger.flights.where(CONDITION).sum(:value)
```

gives me the sum of values of the flights.

Now I am trying to do something like

```
passenger.flights.where(CONDITION).extras.sum(:value)
```

Which, of course, gives me an error:

```
undefined method `extras' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

Usually I would use has_many through to get all extras for a passenger. But since I have the WHERE filter in between I don't know how to do this.

I hope the problem became clear.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins).

If, under the Passenger model, you have `has_many :extras, through: :flights`, you can just do (note the condition is just random to highlight the use of `table_name.column_name`):

`passenger.extras.joins(:flight).where('flights.date > ? or flights.date < ?', some_date, some_other_date).sum(:value)`

Comment: Thanks, this returns:  Can't join 'Extra' to association named 'flights'

Comment: Try `joins(:flight)`

Answer (score 1):

```
passenger.flights.where(CONDITION).joins(:extras).sum('extras.value')
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!